# Get first product ordered by customer

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, row-number

I have an existing table like below. I want to replace the NULLs in first_product column with the first product a customer has ordered.

INPUT

| customer_id | product | order_date_id | first_product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C0001 | apple | 20220224 | NULL |
| C0001 | pear | 20220101 | NULL |
| C0002 | strawberry | 20220224 | NULL |
| C0001 | apple | 20220206 | NULL |

OUTPUT:

| customer_id | product | order_date_id | first_product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C0001 | apple | 20220224 | pear |
| C0001 | pear | 20220101 | pear |
| C0002 | strawberry | 20220224 | strawberry |
| C0001 | apple | 20220206 | pear |

I have thought about using row numbers as below, but not sure how to pull it all together.
I have this code so far, but not sure how to update the first_product column using the below code.

```sql
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY customer_id, order_date_id) AS first_occurrance
```

Some pseudo-code:

```
REPLACE first_product FROM table WITH product WHERE
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY customer_id, order_date_id) AS first_occurrance =  1
```

Comment: `ORDER BY customer_id` is not needed when you have `PARTITION BY customer_id` before it.

Comment: When selecting the `ROW_NUMBER()` you know which is the first order for that customer.  Can you show, with some sampledata, where you are lost?

Comment: I've edited the question, hope it makes more sense now!

Comment: BTW: Which order is the first_product, for customer_id='C0001', he bought apples and pears?

Comment: Can you correct type order_date_it where it says "2022020" ?

Comment: Corrected the order dates

Comment: Are you using Spark? Are you using Delta format?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use `first` window function and achieve this.

```scala
val cust_data = Seq[(String, String, Int, String)](
                            ("C0001",   "apple",    20220224,   null),
                            ("C0001",   "pear",    20220101,    null),
                            ("C0002",   "strawberry",   20220224,   null),
                            ("C0001",   "apple",    20220206,   null)
                   ).toDF("cust_id", "product", "date_id", "first_prod")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val out_df = cust_data.withColumn("first_prod", first($"product").over(Window.partitionBy($"cust_id").orderBy($"date_id")))


out_df.show()

+-------+----------+--------+----------+
|cust_id|   product| date_id|first_prod|
+-------+----------+--------+----------+
|  C0001|      pear|20220101|      pear|
|  C0001|     apple|20220206|      pear|
|  C0001|     apple|20220224|      pear|
|  C0002|strawberry|20220224|strawberry|
+-------+----------+--------+----------+
```